# iOS7 UITabBarController not responding after programmatically changing selectedViewController or selectedIndex

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

As stated above I'm having problems regarding UITabBarController or specifically the tab bar not responding after manually/programmatically setting the selectedViewController or selectedIndex. This also happens when I pop the view controller of the previously selected tab before moving to another tab screen. Yes I believe I have checked the multiple times the delegate for UITabBarController and yes I have confirmed that the

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

is not being fired. Is there anyone who has experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure set the delegate right, if not, the delegate method won't be fired.

Comment: Yes it's set properly like I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like loading behavior of assets might have changed in iOS7

Make sure that the view is completely loaded.

Prior to iOS7, you would create the tabbed view, push it, then select the tab.

in ios7, the view is not loaded synchronously. So while you did create it and display it, the select index gets called before it is actually shown and therefore has no effect.

At least this is what bit me as we have started to transition to iOS7